# Java array not functioning properly?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maintest {
    static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println("This is how you should format your equation => 3.0 x + 5.5 y = 9.0");
        System.out.println("Type your first equation:");
        String first = kb.nextLine();
        //first equation
        Scanner one = new Scanner(first);
        //scanner for first
        double[] arr = new double[6];
        //arr containing numbers
        String[] vars = new String[2];
        //arr containing variable names
        System.out.println("Type your second equation:");
        String second = kb.nextLine();
        //second equations
        Scanner two = new Scanner(second);
        //scanner for second
        one.useDelimiter("[^\\p{Alnum},\\.-]");
        two.useDelimiter("[^\\p{Alnum},\\.-]");
        //anything other than alphanumberic characters,
        //comma, dot or negative sign is skipped
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            if (one.hasNextDouble())
                arr[i-1] = one.nextDouble();
            else if (one.hasNext())
                vars[i-1] = one.next();
            else if (two.hasNextDouble())
                arr[i+2] = one.nextDouble();
            else if (arr[i-1] == 0.0)
                arr[i-1] = 1.0;
            //putting values into array
        }
        System.out.println(arr[3]);
        System.out.println(vars[2]);
    }
}
```

I was wondering what is wrong with my code. It is supposed to solve linear Systems of Equations, but right now, I am working on taking the values from the equations that the person would type in. I was expecting it to print out the value of the specific index of the array I told it to print(i.e., the arr[3] and the vars[2]), but it says java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2. Could you please help and possibly tell me my mistake? Oh, and I wanted to know a more efficient way to complete the same amount of code, maybe even with the user being able to type just 3x+4.5y=15 without all the unnecessary spaces or .0's.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you see when you step through your code in your debuger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, `vars` is a size two array:

```
String[] vars = new String[2];
```

Since Java indexes from zero, that means the array has "room" for two Strings: `vars[0]` and `vars[1]`. Anything beyond that is out-of-bounds, which is why you get the error:

```
System.out.println(vars[2]); //vars[2] would be the third String, but vars's length is only two!
```

You should also make sure you're not trying to access `vars[2]` in the loop preceding the print statement.